# Как правильно организовывать работу нескольких приложений на 1 VDS?

Tags: ubuntu, vds, virtual-hosts

Развернул 2 приложения на 1 VDS (на разных портах). При развертывании приложений задался вопросом имеет ли смысл создавать отдельного пользователя на отдельное приложение?

Конечно, думаю что с точки безопасности - это вроде как имеет смысл, а с точки зрения производительности? Будет ли система потреблять больше ресурсов или ничего не изменится?

И надо ли создавать для каждого приложения отдельно виртуальное окружение? Может, иметь только 1 общее, просто пути прописать для каждого приложения?

Да, понимаю, что виртуальное окружение работает как песочница - чисто под нужды проекта, но если несколько проектов могут работать на 1 виртуальном окружении - это же какая экономия места на диске...

Кто как решает эти вопросы?

Comment: Создаю отдельных пользователей и отдельные виртуальные окружения (не так уж и много места они у меня занимают)

Comment: @andreymal, ну просто бывают огромные библиотеки, например, **catboost**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не хочу агитировать Вас за очевидное, но я бы поместил каждое приложение в отдельный докер - контейнер, а перед ними поставил бы nginx, который по именам "разруливает", на какой из контейнеров "кинуть коннект".

А всё это описал в одном докер-композе.

Премущества:

Все приложения работают на стандартных портах, разница - только  имени. Например, `app1.mydomain.ru` и `app2.mydomain.ru`

во вторых, у Вас есть строгая изоляция. даже не на уровне виртуальных окрежений, а на гораздо более "изолированном" уровне докер-контейнеров.

Предположим, вы встали не с той ноги и переписали одно из приложений на Go. Нет проблем! в виде контейнера оно установится на Ваш хостинг точно так же.

Экономия места тут работает так: если мы "наследуемся" от одного образа - то место занимают только "различия".

Ну, и наконец, это "очень протоптанная дорога": сейчас так делают примерно все и примерно всё. :-) Это означает, что советов - надают!

Comment: а что насчет пользователей? Имеет смыл для каждого APP заводить своего или оставить все на 1?

Comment: Вот кстати "Все приложения работают на ... портах" это недостаток. Я на своих серверах перевёл всё на UNIX-сокеты и в пределах локалхоста никакие порты вообще не использую - повторить такое с контейнерами будет как минимум затруднительно

Comment: @andreymal - интересная мысль, спасибо, что заронили мне её в голову.. Кстати, как по скорости? Выиигрыш, или не мерили?

Comment: @S.H. не мерил (да и смысла мало, мои серверы слабо нагружены). Но помимо скорости ещё одно преимущество в том, что доступ к UNIX-сокетам можно регулировать стандартными средствами ОС (chmod, chown, POSIX ACL), в то время как к портам может подключиться кто угодно и придётся велосипедировать авторизацию (возможно, я слишком параноик, но я админю сервер, на всякий случай исходя из предположения, что потенциальный злоумышленник может залогиниться в систему в роли обычного пользователя, так что я не доверяю даже локалхосту)

Answer (score 1):

Создание различных пользователей и/или различных виртуальных окружений зависит от схожести стеков самих приложений. 
Из личного опыта, я не создаю различных пользователей для приложений, но точно создаю раздельные виртуальные окружения. 
С приложениями работаю через screen, утилита позволяет работать с "окнами" терминала.

```
sudo apt install screen
```

Чтобы создать окно используется флаг -S

```
screen -S some_screen_name
```

После чего ты окажешься в "отдельном" окне терминала, там же ты можешь работать с конкретным приложением.
**Чтобы выйти обратно нужно нажать ctrl + A и потом D**

Чтобы перейти в уже созданное окно, используется флаг -r

```
screen -r some_screen_name
```

Таким образом можно создать несколько необходимых папок с виртуальными окружениями и комфортно с ними работать через screen. 
Если ты решишь делать отдельных пользователей, то screen будет так же удобен.